# Flutter sets textfield cursor to start when changing controller's text

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a reusable text field class like so:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String value = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: MyTextField(
            value: value,
            onChange: (val) {
              setState(() {
                value = val;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

typedef ChangeCallback = void Function(String value);

class MyTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  final ChangeCallback onChange;
  final String value;

  const MyTextField({this.onChange = _myDefaultFunc, this.value = ""});
  
  static _myDefaultFunc(String value){}

  @override
  _MyTextFieldState createState() => _MyTextFieldState();
}

class _MyTextFieldState extends State<MyTextField> {
  final controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller.text = widget.value;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant MyTextField oldWidget) {
    controller.text = widget.value;
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      controller: controller,
      onChanged: (value) {
        widget.onChange(value);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, if the value is changed then `onChange` callback is called and also the value is again sent back to `TextField`. The problem with this is every time I update the value, `TextField` sets the cursor always to the start. Probably because the updated value is sent back to the `TextField` everytime? Not sure. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to update values in didUpdateWidget

```
//@override
//   void didUpdateWidget(covariant MyTextField oldWidget) {
//     controller.text = widget.value;
//     super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
//   }
```

I just commented-out this function and the code works fine
below is the complete code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String value = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(children: [
          SizedBox(height:50),
          Text("text input: $value"),
          SizedBox(height:50),
          Center(
            child: MyTextField(
              value: value,
              onChange: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  value = val;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}

typedef ChangeCallback = void Function(String value);

class MyTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  final ChangeCallback onChange;
  final String value;

  const MyTextField({this.onChange = _myDefaultFunc, this.value = ""});

  static _myDefaultFunc(String value) {}

  @override
  _MyTextFieldState createState() => _MyTextFieldState();
}

class _MyTextFieldState extends State<MyTextField> {
  final controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller.text = widget.value;
    super.initState();
  }

//   @override
//   void didUpdateWidget(covariant MyTextField oldWidget) {
//     controller.text = widget.value;
//     super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
//   }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      controller: controller,
      onChanged: (value) {
        widget.onChange(value);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `onChanged` method to get the value of text field, pass a `TextEditingController`.

```
class MyTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final String defaultValue;

  const MyTextField({@required this.controller, this.defaultValue = ''});

  @override
  _MyTextFieldState createState() => _MyTextFieldState();
}

class _MyTextFieldState extends State<MyTextField> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    widget.controller.text = widget.defaultValue;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      controller: widget.controller,
    );
  }
}
```

This way, you can declare a `TextEditingController` in the parent widget to get the value like you would normally do with Flutter's native `TextFormField`.